# Too many fields in query output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a query and I only want to output three variables

```
Relationship.select('follower_id as source, followed_id as target, value').map(&:attributes)
```

however the result I am getting includes the id variable as below which I dont want. How do I get rid of it?

```
{"source"=>1, "target"=>3, "value"=>1, "id"=>nil}, 
{"source"=>1, "target"=>4, "value"=>1, "id"=>nil}, 
{"source"=>1, "target"=>5, "value"=>1, "id"=>nil}, 
{"source"=>2, "target"=>3, "value"=>1, "id"=>nil}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` always returns `id` attribute, you can get rid of it in `map`:

```
Relationship.select('follower_id as source, followed_id as target, value').map{|x| [x.source, x.target, x.value]}
```